# fragment import type

Tags: android, import, fragment

I'm trying to load a map fragment and I have a problem with the imports:

If the map fragment class imports **android.support.v4.app.Fragment**, in the other fragment I get an error on replace() method becouse it requires type **android.app.Fragment**.

```
Maps_fragment mapsf = new Maps_fragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("latitud", instalacion.Latitud);
        bundle.putString("longitud", instalacion.Longitud);
        bundle.putString("titulo", instalacion.Nombre);
        bundle.putBoolean("editable", false);
        mapsf.setArguments(bundle);

        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContenedor, mapsf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

But if the map fragment imports *android.app.Fragment*, I can replace but I get another error "*Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'android.app.Fragment' to 'com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment'*" on this line:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Any solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change SupportMapFragment to MapFragment?

Comment: ok that works. Thank you!

Comment: I'll make an answer. Please upvote/accept! :)

Comment: Thanks. I can't upvote becouse I need 15+ reputation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change `SupportMapFragment` to `MapFragment`. Alternatively, you could change `getChildFragmentManager...` to the support version of the method, but that is more work.